# Get row which contains maximum value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in SQL Server containing sales data as follows.

```
seq_no  Itemid  Unit    pcs value
------------------------------------   
1       501     101     1   1001.48
1       502     102     2   1004.25
1       502     102     7    987.58
1       503     103     3    787.58
1       503     103     7    647.87
1       503     103     9   1478.58
1       504     104     2    202.25
1       504     104     3    365.87
1       504     104     7    102.25
1       504     104     6    322.22
1       505     105     1   2000.01
1       505     105     2    914.02
```

Now I want unit wise maximum value records. Means when I grouping on `seq_no, itemid, unit` and getting summing of pcs, and value, its giving result as follows.

Itemwise Summary

```
seq_no   itemid  unit  pcs   value
------------------------------------
1        501     101    1   1001.48
1        502     102    9   1991.83
1        503     103   19   2914.03
1        504     104   12    992.59
1        505     105    3   2914.03
```

Now you can see, I have two different records which has maximum value (2914.03) (eg. 3rd and 5th record). I need 3rd record because It has maximum value with maximum pcs. In my case I want following:

```
seq_no   itemid  unit  pcs   value
-------------------------------------
1        503     105    19  2914.03
```

How do I get this result, without harming performance, because this table has so many rows?

Comment: order by value+pcs or value*10000+pcs if pcs not exceed 10000

Comment: 3rd and 5th record are having different Unit numbers so the query should be fine right as you are retrieving unit wise maximum value records. However if you are to filter by pcs without worrying about the unit number then a Top 1 with descending order sort on Value and pcs should do the trick

Comment: @GouriShankarAechoor [Backticks are for code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text), so please don't use them for random highlighting.

Comment: What to select if 3rd and 5th have the same pcs?

Comment: @hvd there was a reason to highlight it as I wanted to bring notice to "unit wise maximum value records". Anyways, I will keep in mind for later. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT TOP 1 seq_no,
item_id,unit,
SUM(pcs) AS 'pcs',
SUM(value) AS 'value'
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY item_id,seq_no,unit
ORDER BY value DESC,pcs DESC
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e74cf/3)**

Comment: I have tried this, and It is working well. but I have to use thie query as sub-query, and jointing many other tables too. and order by not working in subquery. I have also tried window function, but that has another problems too. sorry for forgot this mention in my question.

Comment: The whole effort goes waste rite?

Comment: I am really very sorry for that.

Comment: @ManishSapkal `ORDER BY` does work in subqueries when combining it with `TOP`. [Here's an example.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ad5709/1) What is it, specifically, that isn't working for you?

Comment: @Manish Sapkal, why do you think sub query will hurt performance? What's problem with window function?

Comment: @hvd, does TOP hurts performance? I am asking you because, I really did not know.

Comment: @ManishSapkal Possibly, but not necessarily. There's no hard rule on what performs poorly and what doesn't. If you want to have a reasonable expectation as to whether it will scale well, execute the simplest possible query that you expect might not perform well, and look at the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM   itemwise_summary
ORDER BY value desc, pcs desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
WITH res AS  (

SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY seq_no)rnum, 
seq_no,ItemID,unit,SUM(pcs)sum_pcs,SUM(VALUE)sum_val FROM tbl_name 
GROUP BY seq_no,ItemID,unit
)

SELECT TOP  1 * FROM res ORDER BY sum_pcs DESC,sum_val DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select max(value),* from table
```

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(seq_no int,item_id int,Unit int,pcs int,value bigint);

insert into tbl1 VALUES(1,501,101,1,1001.48);
insert into tbl1 VALUES(1,502,102,2,1004.25);
insert into tbl1 VALUES(1,502,102,7,987.58);
insert into tbl1 VALUES(1,503,103,3,787.58);
insert into tbl1 VALUES(1,503,103,7,647.87);
insert into tbl1 VALUES(1,503,103,9,1478.58);
insert into tbl1 VALUES(1,504,104,2,202.25);
insert into tbl1 VALUES(1,504,104,3,365.87);
insert into tbl1 VALUES(1,504,104,7,102.25);
insert into tbl1 VALUES(1,504,104,6,322.22);
insert into tbl1 VALUES(1,505,105,1,2000.01);
insert into tbl1 VALUES(1,505,105,2,914.02);
select * from tbl1;



with cte(seq_no,a,b,c,d)as(
select x.seq_no ,x.item_id,x.Unit,sum(x.pcs),sum(x.value) from  (
select seq_no,item_id,Unit,pcs,value ,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by unit order by value) as rnk
from tbl1
)x group by  x.seq_no,x.item_id,x.Unit
)select seq_no,sum(a)/5 as item_id,MAX(b)as Unit, MAX(c)as pcs,MAX(d)as value from cte
group by seq_no
```

This one is working correct ple check.